# How to wire a light to existing junction box that has red, black, white, ground wire coming in

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a little bit of a conundrum. I've inherited a cabin that was 90% complete, but there a few little jobs left, one being a light junction box in my pantry that I need to hook a light up to. It's already drywalled so I can't see where wires are going, and there is no obvious light switch. I have 3 sets of wires coming into the junction that are capped together, plus the ground wire. It looks like this:

[image: Image of Junction box wiring]

[image: Image with wiring shown]

I'm assuming white is neutral, black is hot, and red is usually another hot? I've used a multimeter and when checking the black and white wires I get a voltage reading, when I check the white and red together I get no reading.

There's a working/functional 3-way light switch on the outside of the pantry for lights located on a staircase nearby but I don't think that would be the switch for this as it would just be an odd set up.

I'm guessing it could just be wired to have a light with a pull chord or turn switch on the light to turn things on and off. Is that possible? Meaning the power is always on to this junction and the light fixture will have to control the on/off?

Anyway, looking for some advice, I can check things with a multimeter etc. to help diagnose what is wired up here, but all I really want to do is hook up a light here without frying myself or burning the cabin down.

Thanks for any advice, appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  While this is well-drawn, your stylization has elided some important information.  It matters how the wires are grouped into cables or conduit ports, so it would help if you could illustrate that.

Comment: Of course, sorry about that.  I've edited the post and added an image to illustrate that.

Comment: Can you look in the two boxes directly connected to this one and see what the red wire does there?

Comment: I am not sure where these two wires go. There is a wall socket below it near the floor (this is a wall fixture) I'll pull that apart and report back.

Comment: Sometimes 2 hotts (both red and black) go to a fixture where a fan light combo could be installed at a later date and one may not be connected at the switch location.

Comment: So it's on a completely different circuit than the staircase lights and the wall socket. It picks up on a circuit that runs the power to some lights and sockets upstairs (this is downstairs), and I can't find exactly where it goes/comes from. Is there anyway to test for that? @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: It would seem from it's location and with no switch or wiring close by that it was intended to have a light with a switch on the fixture, is this a likely scenario?

Comment: @Harper I edited the post to include the drawing you asked for.

Comment: I was afraid of that. We can guess but need more info of how the other boxes are wired to be sure (at the other controlling switches and light).  Any insight into those?

Comment: @Harper I can investigate tomorrow as best I can. Thanks for your help so far. Quick question, should I get a reading on the Red wire? Or does that depend where it comes from/goes to?  White and Black gives me a voltage reading on the meter.

Comment: White gives you a voltage reading?  Not a great sign but we need more info. I would also try different combinations of switch positions and see if the hot moves around. The contents of the other boxes may tell the tale.  Super important: in 3-way switches screw color matters: black vs brass.

Comment: @Harper When i say black and white gives me a reading, I meant that when I make contact with White and Black with the meter I get the voltage reading, but when I contact the White and Red I get no reading.

Comment: @CabinDIY Oh. You are presuming that white is neutral.  **Not a safe bet where 3-ways are involved**. *Disclaimer: You must never intentionally use ground as a current return; neutral is not ground.*  However ground is handy as a reference voltage for momentary testing like this.  Test the voltages relative to ground.

Comment: @Harper, okay I see, so contact each colored wire with the ground wire using a meter and see what gives back a voltage reading?

Comment: Yup.  And then try it again with switches in different positions.

Comment: @Harper As far as I can find there is no switch/switchbox for this junction, I've been looking everywhere. Only Black wire gives a voltage reading when when in contact with ground through the multimeter. Trying to avoid having to pull down drywall thats already up and painted.

Comment: @Harper - okay another possibility, could this junction be possibly intended to be used for a wired smoke detector because I found one more junction box upstairs on the wall high up near the ceiling with the same configuration.  This article tends to make me think so: [Smoke Detector Install](https://www.homedepot.com/c/smoke_detector_placement_and_where_to_install_HT_PG_EL)

Comment: And you've thrown all the 3-way switches in the area?  If it's a 3-way inline, I'd expect it to either light up red instead of black, or in addition to black (the preferred for your objective).  Otherwise your theory about smoke detectors may be correct.